# Excel More Than 2 Contains Filter?

Tags: excel

I'm having a bit of a filtering problem. For simplicity let's say this is my data set.

```
  Employee Building

Bob           1, 3 

Tim           2, 4

John          2, 3

Matt          2, 6
```

I Want to create a filter so I can find all employees that work in either building, 1, 3 or 6. So in this case it would filter Tim out. If it was just two criteria I could create a filter and go to contains, and type 1 then OR 2. Basically I'm limited by the fact that there are just 2 fields there. Can I expand this? Some suggestions I've read were to use Advanced Filter but all the examples I saw, it wouldn't work since each column contained a single data point.

Edit: Data didn't come out the way I had intended but I have two columns. One for employee Name. One for Building. The building column has multiple data points in one cell, as one employee could work in more than building.

Comment: You are experiencing the downside of having more than one data item in a single cell. Try better data architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is best visible in this form, I could use the text> Column and split it out based on the commas which are present, but even then I'm not sure how I'd go from there

Answer (score 0):

You need a "helper column".

With data in columns **A** & **B**, in **C2** enter:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("1",B2))+ISNUMBER(FIND("3",B2))+ISNUMBER(FIND("6",B2))
```

and copy down:

[image]
Then apply the AutoFilter to hide the rows that contain ***0*** in column **C**.